# About spherical coordinates

Tags: spherical-coordinates

I will post an image which believe it is essential to understand the question:
See the image:
[Figure book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E39mQ.png)

> Spherical coordinates $r, \theta, \phi$ are perfectly intuitive
> because the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ correspond, respectively, to
> longitude and latitude on the surface of the Earth, and $r$ is the
> distance to the center of the Earth.

I believe the notation is wrong, since theta is the angle wrt north and south axis, shouldn't be the reverse?

Answer (score 0):

Which textbook is this taken from? If it is a mathematics textbook, the convention is that $\phi$ corresponds to latitude and $\theta$ to longitude, but if it is a physics textbook, then $\theta$ will usually correspond to latitude and $\phi$ to longitude. This sort of confusion is why I usually stay away from spherical coordinates.

Comment: It is latitude and longitude in the geographical sense? Because it is what is giving me trouble, but if is a definition that the angle theta, for example, is called latitude, ok.. It is from "Introduction to Tensor analysis" Pavel

Comment: It seems that you are reading a mathematics textbook, so, yes $\theta$ and $\phi$ correspond to geographical longitude and latitude ("prime meridian" is xz plane with positive x, and "north pole" is positive z-axis)

Answer (score 0):

The $(r,\theta,\phi)$ convention for three dimensional spherical polar coordinates is used in mathematics, as it follows naturally from the $(r,\theta)$ convention used for the two dimensional case. However, physicists for some bizarre reason prefer $(r,\phi,\theta)$. What makes it **even more confusing** is that the very order the coordinates are written is also sometimes switched. Some authors order it as **radial, azimuthal, polar** which seems reasonable whereas some authors use **radial, polar, azimuthal** instead. So *even if* the author says "I'll use the $(r,\phi,\theta)$ convention" it might not even mean what you think it does!

So, if you're using spherical coordinates, it's best to *explicitly state* the coordinate transformation you're using. Here's a passage from some recent work of mine:

> I will also use the $\displaystyle ( r,\theta ,\phi )$ convention for spherical coordinates, as used by Wolfram Mathworld. Explicitly, the coordinate transformation is
> \begin{equation*}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> x\\
> y\\
> z
> \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
> r\cos \theta \sin \phi \\
> r\sin \theta \sin \phi \\
> r\cos \phi 
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{equation*}

Suggested reading: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html

Comment: Yes, this convection give the names to the angle that agree what i believe be the geographical convention, that is, phi will measure the latitude, and theta the longitude.
So see my post image, where phi and theta are changed, with this i believe the author changed the angle figure, but remain its name in agreement with your link